# SharePoint 2010 - GUI automated test tool

Tags: silverlight

I´m searching for an automated GUI test tool for SharePoint 2010.
At the moment I´m creating automated GUI tests with PowerShell(IE Com Object) and Selenium(Creating with Selenium IDE and playing with RC Control at the IE).
But in both cases they have a big problem with Silverlight (At the moment I must deactivate SL)
Is there any other automated GUI test tool? Is it possible to automate Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Team Foundation Server for UI tests. Chris O'Brien did a presentation on this at the UK Best Practices Conference. You can have a look at his slide deck on his blog at
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/04/automated-sharepoint-buildsui.html

He's going to be working on some more information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

There is another Testing-Tool: [TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/) *(which is a commercial product, btw)*
It is pretty powerful, but i do not know how it handles Silverlight.
But there is a 30 day trial, so you can at least try it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio and can upgrade to Ultimate they have a way you can script tests, or record and edit tests to run on SharePoint.   It's what I use for most of the GUI verification and for regression tests...haven't done much with Silverlight yet but I've had no problems with hitting those pages.